# How to get this nested form to create a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

My Rails 5 application includes two models, Activity and Timeslot.

activity.rb

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :club
  has_many :timeslots, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :timeslots
  validates :club_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

timeslot.rb

```
class Timeslot < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :activity
    validates :time_start, presence: true
    validates :time_end, presence: true
    validates :day, presence: true
    #validates :activity_id, presence: true (I realised this was causing one of the errors I had)
    default_scope -> { order(day: :asc) }
end
```

When I create my activity, I'd also like to create it's first timeslot on the same page, same form.

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@activity) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name, "Class name" %>*
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.fields_for :timeslots do |timeslots_form| %>
                    <%= timeslots_form.label :time_start, "Start time" %>
                    <%= timeslots_form.time_select :time_start %>

                    <%= timeslots_form.label :time_end, "End time" %>
                    <%= timeslots_form.time_select :time_end %>

                    <%= timeslots_form.label :day %>
                    <%= timeslots_form.select :day, (0..6).map {|d| [Date::DAYNAMES[d], d]} %>
            <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Create class", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

My edit/update version of this seems to be working fine.

activities_controller.rb

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
 ...

def new
    @activity = Activity.new
    @activity.timeslots.build
end

def create
    @activity = current_club.activities.build(activity_params)
    #@activity.timeslots.first.activity_id = @activity.id (I thought this might solve the problem, but didn't)
    if @activity.save
        flash[:success] = "New class created!"
        redirect_to activities_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @activity = current_club.activities.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @activity.timeslots.build
end

def update
    @activity = current_club.activities.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @activity.update_attributes(activity_params)
        flash[:sucess] = "Class updated!"
        redirect_to edit_activity_path(@activity)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
...

private

    def activity_params
        params.require(:activity).permit(:name, :active, #active is set to default: true
                                         :timeslots_attributes => [:id,
                                                                   :time_start,
                                                                   :time_end,
                                                                   :day,
                                                                   :active])
    end
end
```

But whenever I try to create a new activity I get the error message "Timeslots activities must exist".

I feel it's trying to assign the activity_id for timeslot before the activity is created, but I'm not sure. I've tried many things (some of which I've included in my example in comment form) but am unable to work out why I'm getting this error.

Update: Add error log

```
Started POST "/activities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-09-25 18:04:51 +0700
Processing by ActivitiesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xp+dBcWC4cjI6FLpIqhU0RzM4ldZ4JpkFLSyAXcmifL73QqWz6R65EHm/Tj7QxlXnWiBA0axjVXvMZHQ+XKA9A==", "activity"=>{"name"=>"Newest class", "timeslots_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"time_start(1i)"=>"2016", "time_start(2i)"=>"9", "time_start(3i)"=>"25", "time_start(4i)"=>"12", "time_start(5i)"=>"00", "time_end(1i)"=>"2016", "time_end(2i)"=>"9", "time_end(3i)"=>"25", "time_end(4i)"=>"13", "time_end(5i)"=>"30", "day"=>"4"}}}, "commit"=>"Create class"}
  Club Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "clubs".* FROM "clubs" WHERE "clubs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering activities/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered activities/new.html.erb within layouts/application (16.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (58.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 111ms (Views: 93.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Comment: Show your full error log from your terminal

Comment: Updated my question to include the error log

Comment: Where is the error that you are witnessing because the log doesn't show any errors and your code seems fine?

Comment: Instead of an `INSERT INTO` statement I'm getting `rollback transaction`. No new activity is being created in the database. The error message I'm referring to appears on my page through `object.errors.full_messages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because Rails 5 makes belongs_to attribute required by default. Also, the saving mechanism kind of follows:

```
validate your parent model
validate your child model # validation fails here because parent doesn't have an id yet, because it hasn't been saved
save parent model
save child model
```

A way to resolve this is to:

```
class Activity < AR
  has_many :timeslots, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :activity
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :timeslots
end

class Timeslot < AR
  belongs_to :activity, inverse_of: :timeslot
end
```

You could learn more of this [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html) and [here](https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Form is now working. The second link you provided addressed the exact problem I was facing.